# Stored procedure returning integer instead of ISingleResult

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VCT_SP_SUBJECT_EMAIL_REMINDER]
AS
CREATE TABLE #tempEstimatedDates(
SUBJECT_ID int,
FIRST_NAME varchar(200),
LAST_NAME varchar(200),
MIDDLE_NAME varchar(200),
EMAIL_ID varchar(200),
ACTIVITY_VALUE datetime,
SUB_VISIT_ID int,
VISIT_NO INT,
VISIT_DETAIL_ID INT,
PROTOCOL_ID INT,
LOCATION_ID INT,
SITE_ID INT,
SITE_NAME VARCHAR(200),
PROTOCOL_NAME VARCHAR(200)  
)
INSERT INTO   

#tempEstimatedDates(SUBJECT_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,EMAIL_ID,      
ACTIVITY_VALUE,
SUB_VISIT_ID,VISIT_NO,VISIT_DETAIL_ID,PROTOCOL_ID       
 ,LOCATION_ID,PROTOCOL_NAME,SITE_ID,SITE_NAME) 
SELECT * FROM dbo.[GET_SUBJECT_SCHEDULE]('Estimated Date Of Next Visit')

---TABLE FOR ACTUAL DATE OF VISIT---
CREATE TABLE #tempActualDates(
SUBJECT_ID int,
FIRST_NAME varchar(200),
LAST_NAME varchar(200),
MIDDLE_NAME varchar(200),
EMAIL_ID varchar(200),
ACTIVITY_VALUE datetime,
SUB_VISIT_ID int,
VISIT_NO INT,
VISIT_DETAIL_ID INT,
PROTOCOL_ID INT,
LOCATION_ID INT,
SITE_ID INT,
SITE_NAME VARCHAR(200),
PROTOCOL_NAME VARCHAR(200)  
)
INSERT INTO 

 #tempActualDates(SUBJECT_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,EMAIL_ID,
 ACTIVITY_VALUE,SUB_VISIT_ID,
VISIT_NO,VISIT_DETAIL_ID,PROTOCOL_ID ,LOCATION_ID,PROTOCOL_NAME,SITE_ID,SITE_NAME) 
SELECT * from dbo.[GET_SUBJECT_SCHEDULE]('Actual Date Of Visit')
select * from #tempEstimatedDates 
where  subject_id in 
(select subject_id from #tempActualDates) and visit_no not in (select visit_NO from   
#tempActualDates)
AND 
(   convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101)=convert(varchar,getdate(),101)
or dateadd(d,2,convert(varchar,getdate()  
,101))=convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101)  
or dateadd(d,1,convert(varchar,getdate() ,101))=convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101)
)
UNION
select * from #tempEstimatedDates
where  subject_id NOT in 
(select subject_id from #tempActualDates)
AND 
(   convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101)=convert(varchar,getdate(),101)
or dateadd(d,2,convert(varchar,getdate()  
,101))=convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101)  
or dateadd(d,1,convert(varchar,getdate() ,101))=convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101)
)
select * from #tempEstimatedDates 
where  subject_id in 
(select subject_id from #tempActualDates) and visit_no not in (select visit_NO from   
#tempActualDates)
AND 
(   --convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101)=convert(varchar,getdate(),101) or 
DATEDIFF(d,convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101),convert(varchar,getdate()  
,101))=2    
or DATEDIFF(d,convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101),convert(varchar,getdate()  
,101))=1    
)
UNION
select * from #tempEstimatedDates
where  subject_id NOT in 
(select subject_id from #tempActualDates)
AND 
(   --convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101)=convert(varchar,getdate(),101) OR
DATEDIFF(d,convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101),convert(varchar,getdate()  
 ,101))=2   
or DATEDIFF(d,convert(varchar,ACTIVITY_VALUE,101),convert(varchar,getdate() 
,101))=1    
)
drop table #tempEstimatedDates
drop table #tempActualDates
```

This is my stored procedure which returns two tables of data in sql server. But when i drag and drop this SP in dbml its return type becomes int instead of Isingleresult. how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem as well which was definitely caused by temp tables. The way I fixed it was to add

```
SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

to the start of the stored procedure. The solution is taken from [this blog](http://softscenario.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/entiy-framework-add-function-import-get.html) which talks about Entity Framework but the same seems to apply to Linq to Sql.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why but this one saved me!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in the past. I think its down to having temporary tables in the SP. I can't remember exactly how I got around it but I think it had something to do with using a user defined function instead of a stored proc.

Is there no way you could achieve this using Linq-to-Sql instead of an SP?

Comment: please give me some idea like how to make UDF for this

Comment: Sorry, I can't really remember. You should be able to google on how to create UDF's. Once you have created it you will be able to add it to you .dbml file the same as your use an SP.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your Temp tables this way `DECLARE @TempTable TABLE` instead of `CREATE TABLE #tempActualDates` and you will be good to go.